# Getting ripped only by dumbells

Tags: exercise, gym, health, dumbbells, programs

I am a man who, due to privacy issues, do not like to go to the gym. But one of my biggest dreams, like any other men in my age (20's), is to have a beautiful body and ripped muscles.

I have been trying to do some home-exercise and have gotten some quite good results without even using any tools. However, decreasing the fat on my body is not my goal. I want to have a ripped body without going to the fitness and I was thinking about buying myself some dumbbells.

Is it possible to get a ripped body using dumbbells at home and following a good and healthy food-program?

Comment: In addition to dumbbells, many exercises benefit from being done on a bench, invest in one if you have room and funds.

Comment: http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Instructions.html you can find instructions for how to design a workout here.  You can start with a total body workout.  For each body part targeted, just browse to the dumbbell section of the exercises.

Comment: In general: prioritize compound movements (movement in more than one joint) over isolated movements.  For each exercise, continue doing reps until you physically can't do it anymore.  You can get away with doing one set of reps per exercise.  As a beginner, anything you do will produce rapid results.  Remember to use good form so you don't injure yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 good programmes I am aware of that are dumbbell focused. They do require your dumbbells to go up to quite a high weight though.

- [Dumbbell Stopgap](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/zc0uy/a_beginner_dumbbell_program_the_dumbbell_stopgap/)
- [Alternative Dumbbell Stopgap](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/2e79y4/dumbbell_ppl_proposed_alternative_to_dumbbell/)
- [Frankoman's Dumbbell only split](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/frankoman-dumbbell-only-split.html)

### A good program is one you will do consistently.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get a ripped body using dumbells at home and following a good and healthy food-program?

To look ripped you need low-body fat. If you lift heavy and eat at calorie deficit then it's definitely possible to achieve that goal.

Comment: I wonder about the negative vote here, to the only one who takes about how he should eat which is the most important.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can basically train every bodypart using dumbells, let me give some examples:

**Legs: Squats and lunges.** You can start doing squats and lunges to train your legs, once this gets to easy, you can add resistance by holding dumbells in your hands while performing the exercises.

**Arms: Various curls and extension movements.** To train your arms, you can do different variations of bicep curls and tricep extensions, while adding weight using the dumbells to increase resistance.

**Abs: Sit-up variations.** You can do the same here, start with regular sit-ups, and when these get to easy, start adding weight by holding a dumbell in front of your chest, or behind your head to make it harder.

By now you've probably found the pattern in this. For the most part you can start out with small resistance and use dumbells to increase it overtime, making your muscles stronger and bigger.

**Consistency is key here.** You won't get ripped over night, you'll have to stick with it for at least half a year to get notable differences in your physique, but as you might know, most of these "ripped" guys have been training for years.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get ripped even without dumbbels. The main reason or sideffect of getting ripped is due to caloric deficit. You need to eat less calories than you actually burn.
Additional exercise makes this a perfect combination for a 'ripped look'.

All you need is to never stop challenging your body weather that is with increasing the difficulty of calisthenic exercises or adding dumbbels or resistence bands or going to the gym.

So, back to your basic question: YES you can. And I would recommend short crisp and intense whole body exercises like the burpee with dumbbels with adding a push-press into the movement to involve the shoulders a bit. (as an example)

good luck.